# If I'm using a decision tree to predict a quantity, should I "inform" the tree that a certain feature seems exponential? If so, how?

Tags: distributions, fitting

This question is for concreteness. The more general question I have is: Assuming that you have no missing data, what are some practical ways in which fitting a distribution to your data is useful when training an ML model? For instance, say that $X_1$ looks exponential, $X_2$ looks normal, and $X_3$ seems to follow a gamma distribution. What do you **do** with these pieces of information while training up a model?

I ask this question because great pains are taken in intro probability courses to describe the various distributions, and they seem to be referenced fairly often in the sorts of exploratory analyses that I see online, but in the (admittedly few!) ML books I've seen, the famous distributions rarely seem to come up in any practical regard other than *normal* or *not normal*. The various algorithms just seem to "handle" the data that you give them. I feel that I must be missing something, or that I'm failing to connect the dots somehow.

I understand (or at least I believe I understand) that

- certain models make certain assumptions about the distributions of the predictors, and that these assumptions may make certain models a poor choice as a result; for example, if $X_1$ is distributed exponentially, a model that's inherently linear may not be a good choice
- in exploratory analysis, certain *transformations* may suggest themselves; for example, Y may have a clear relationship with $(X_2)^2$
- fitting a distribution can be useful for more precisely predicting the likelihood of future observations and/or for dealing with missing data (presumably, distribution fitting can help you impute more wisely than just choosing the median/mean)

These considerations aside, though, when it comes to training an ML model, is there anything that one should **do** with a fit?

(I'm new to this site, so please forgive me if this question misses the mark in some way. I'm happy to edit based on comments!)

Comment: Out of curiosity, to what "EDA texts" are you referring? The grandaddy of them all, Tukey's *EDA* (1977), makes no mention of any distributions--and that is one of the defining characteristics of EDA from his point of view. Has that really changed so radically in the last 40 years?

Comment: Sorry, that was carelessly phrased. From the exploratory analyses that I've seen (which often take the form of ipython notebooks), I get the sense that distribution fitting -- or, at least, sayings things like "this looks like a Poisson" -- is a frequent activity. I did not have actual "texts" in mind. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thank you.  We do see a lot of questions here, too, where people are concerned about fitting a distribution when there seems to be little or no meaningful purpose to it.  I'm still trying to figure out why that seems so prevalent.